# How can I use a wildcard in uBlock Origin?

Tags: syntax, adblock, browser-addons

How can I use a wildcard in uBlock Origin?  I've tried to figure out how to do it, but I'm a little bit confused.  I just want to simplify all of these rules into one rule:

```
www.dailymail.co.uk###js-article-text > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(2)
www.dailymail.co.uk###js-article-text > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(3)
www.dailymail.co.uk###js-article-text > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(4)
www.dailymail.co.uk###js-article-text > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(5)
www.dailymail.co.uk###js-article-text > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(6)
www.dailymail.co.uk###js-article-text > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(7)
www.dailymail.co.uk###js-article-text > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(9)
www.dailymail.co.uk###js-article-text > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(10)
```

Is it possible to give a range of numbers, or a list of specific numbers, or simply an asterisk?  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use 'odd' and 'even' as placeholders:

```
www.dailymail.co.uk###js-article-text > div:nth-of-type(even) > div:nth-of-type(even)
www.dailymail.co.uk###js-article-text > div:nth-of-type(even) > div:nth-of-type(odd)
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

Comment: That can be simplified to
www.dailymail.co.uk###js-article-text > div:nth-of-type(even) > div:nth-of-type(n)

Answer (score 9):

You may be able to express the desired block with an arithmetic formula. For example, to block all elements except the very first one, use `nth-of-type(n+2)`. Apparently, `n` starts from `0`, so the blocking will skip the first element, but block everything afterwards.

I use this to block articles automatically loaded by the god-awful sites, that employ the "endless stream" approach to reader-engagement...

Answer (score 1):

This will delete from all sites:

```
###js-article-text > div:nth-of-type.*
```

This will delete from only this site

```
www.dailymail.co.uk###js-article-text > div:nth-of-type
```

NOTE: in both cases delete the first line starting with `!`

That line will only do instants, meaning next time you log in it will ignore your rule on any page of that site except that page Deleting line will make rule apply for entire site.

Comment: Wild card # (this will add depth to webpage) so ## is 1 page in ### is page within a page etc..  so (#js-article-text > div:nth-of-type.*) will do main page